# Looking for an efficient way to calculate the correlation of different time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I have 6 temperature sensors (columns) located at different places. Each one offers a measurement each hour. I have $168$ measurements (rows).

I am working on python and I have already used the function `numpy.corrcoeff(my_data)` to obtain the correlation of the whole time series (a $6\times 6$ matrix).

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient between the sensors at shifted times. To do that, I have generated a code in which I remove the first n rows of a sensors 1 and 2 and the last $n$ rows of sensors $3$ to $6$. Then, I have calculated the correlation matrix using $168-n$ rows and the function `numpy.corrcoeff(my_data_shifted)`.

I have also used

```
cross_correlation_aux=np.correlate(my_data[sensor1], 
      np.roll(my_data[sensor2], shift=n))
```

and two nested `for` loops to generate a vector `cross_correlation` appending all cross correlations and finding the maximum as

```
optimal_shift=np.argmax(cross_correlation)
```

I am looking for further alternatives to calculate the correlation shifted between times and sensors. Can someone please suggest me further alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an unified pandas DataFrame that contains the 6 series and add the lagged series you want. That would end up something like:

[image: Dummy dataframe]

Of course the code to create this could get a little messy but you probably can do some simple loops to get it. Then, it is as simples as `df.corr()`. Important to note that this solution can get inefficient as your data gets really big (maybe hundreds of thousands of rows), but I understand that is not your case.